# How to go up a directory in my shebang line?

Tags: python, shebang

OS X using Sublime Text 2.

My app structure is this:

```
/project1/
+———————venv/ <— virtual enviroment
+———————app/ (has an ___init___.py file)<— Flask app
+———————alembic <— current installation of Alembic also has the env.py file
+——————— more files that refer to #!venv/bin/python
```

I'm using Sublime Text 2 to run my scripts, and to tell Sublime Text to use my custom Python install I've so far appended `#!venv/bin/python` to the beginning of my files.

The problem is, now I need to use the virtualenv for a script that resides within the `alembic` directory. `#!venv/bin/python` doesn't work, I guess because `venv` and `alembic` are sibling directories. However, I can't figure out how to go "up" one directory to invoke the correct Python interpreter.

Why doesn't `#!./venv/bin/python` work? doesn't the `.` tell Sublime to go up one directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interpreter path in a shebang instruction must be an absolute path.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Syntax

Comment: Wikipedia says you're right, but `#!../venv/bin/python` *did* work for me. I'm confused.

Comment: Implementations may vary, especially on OSX, I guess. However, it is not wise to rely on non-standard behavior. I believe the real solution would in your case just be a startup script, that can handle also more corner cases.